# Como inserir label dentro da aba no widget notebook do tkinter?

Tags: python, imagem, tkinter, interface, label

Preciso colocar um label dentro de uma "página" do notebook do tkinter. Quando utilizamos o código apresentado abaixo, o label não é posicionado corretamente (não aparece). O mesmo ocorre quando tentamos inserir uma imagem.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.ttk import *


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')

A_frame = Frame(root, width=400, height=400)
B_frame = Frame(root, width=400, height=400)

nb = Notebook(root)
nb.add(A_frame, text='A')
nb.add(B_frame, text='B')
nb.pack()

lb_A = tk.Label(A_frame, text='AAA')
lb_A.place(x=200, y=200)
lb_B = tk.Label(B_frame, text='BBB')
lb_B.place(x=200, y=200)

root.mainloop()
```

Resultado do código:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: o frame que vai dentro do notebook deve usar o notebook como master, pode ser um pouco bagunçado, mas fiz essa aplicação para meu uso, https://github.com/elton1013/dro_fresadora, veja o arquivo gui.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você percisa definir o notebook antes dos frames e usar ele como master dos frames:

```
nb = Notebook(root)
A_frame = Frame(nb, width=400, height=400)
B_frame = Frame(nb, width=400, height=400)
```

Só fazer isso que vai resovler o seu problema.